# How to Add icons in sidebar in Python dash

Tags: python, plotly-dash

Can someone tell me  how to add icons in sidebar of a Python dashboard? I'm   trying to add a small home button in sidebar of my dashboard but when I give the classname it's not working:

```
sidebar = html.Div(
    [
        html.P(
            "A simple sidebar layout with navigation links", className="lead"
        ),
        dbc.Nav(
            [
                dbc.NavLink("Home", href="/home-page", active="exact",**className="fa fa-fw fa-home"**),
                html.Hr(),
                dbc.NavLink("Apply Filters", href="/page-1", active="exact"),
                html.Hr(),
                dbc.NavLink("Upload Documents", href="/page-2", active="exact"),
                html.Hr(),
                dbc.NavLink("Saved Screenshots", href="/page-3", active="exact"),
            ],
            vertical=True,
            pills=True,
        ),
    ],
    style=SIDEBAR_STYLE,
)
```

I'm expecting like this below, not sure how to do

[image: Home Icon]

Answer (score 1):

The icon classes you are using are font awesome icon classes.

The problem is that you haven't included the styles needed for these classes to work.

You can include them like this:

```
app = Dash(
    __name__,
    external_stylesheets=[
        dbc.themes.BOOTSTRAP,
        {
            "href": "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.15.3/css/all.min.css",
            "rel": "stylesheet",
            "integrity": "sha512-iBBXm8fW90+nuLcSKlbmrPcLa0OT92xO1BIsZ+ywDWZCvqsWgccV3gFoRBv0z+8dLJgyAHIhR35VZc2oM/gI1w==",
            "crossorigin": "anonymous",
            "referrerpolicy": "no-referrer",
        },
    ],
)
```